# Apache pool2: examples?

Tags: java, pool

I find **Apache pool2** very different from Apache pool. For instance the purposes of `BasePoolableObjectFactory` are not similar to `BasePooledObjectFactory`.

This stated, there are still no examples on the official website. Now,suppose that you have a class `X` and that you want to create a pool of object `X`s.How can you do that with Apache Pool2?

Here follows class `X`

```
public class X{
  List<Integer> alist;

  public X(){
    alist = new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are some test cases which you can refer about how to use pools:

- [commons/pool2/impl (GoogleSource)](https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-pool/+/refs/heads/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/)
- [commons/pool2 (GoogleSource)](https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-pool/+/refs/heads/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/pool2)